# I am trying to get the last 4 digits of a card number from customer default source

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am having a issue where I have a customer with a default source attached and I want to echo the last 4 digits to the frontend so they can see which card is on file in their account dashboard. Im coding this in php with the stripe API. No matter where I search I seem to be unable to actually get the last four digits to print to the frontend, once I get the last four I also need the expr date to show too I don't know which code to add. Here is my code:

This is in the body

```
<h2 class="" style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;">                                     
<?php
require('./stripe-php/init.php');      

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("STRIPE API KEY");
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($ss_customer_id);
    cardID = $customer->sources->data->last4;
    echo $cardID;
?>
</h2>
```

And at the head

```
// Perform query
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM globalusers WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username']"'");
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
$ss_customer_id = $user['user_token'];
```

Comment: Start by dumping out the values of `$ss_customer_id` and then `$customer` and see what's in there. Chances are something's not what you expected.

Comment: @ceejayoz is right,dump the values,from there you can strip unnecessary parts

Comment: If I dump that then all my users on my website wont be able to make payments, ``` $ss_customer_id ``` is a value in my DB and when a user registers the customer id is locate there so that the customer can be found in my system.

Comment: me deleting or dumping it would break all of that so what i need is to get the current customer signed and print their last 4 digits of the card on file or if there is no card on file then print something like no card on file add one below,

Comment: I got almost all of it working I just need to echo/print the last four from the stripe system. I know its possible but i can't find the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

The comments did not mean 'dump your database', they meant print/log all of the values in the Customer object and you will be able to find where the variable is.

If you're using Payment Methods, this will not work at all - you'll need to [list the Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) and then you'll find it there.

EDIT:

You could maybe try `\Stripe\Customer::retrieve($ss_customer_id, ["expand" => "default_source"])` and then you should find the last4 at I believe `$customer->default_source->last4`.

Comment: Mhm ok, So I know what the variable is but t still is not working, I was the one who created the variables, ss_customer_is is the customer which was assigned at the registration page and is being pulled from the DB thats ok, and $customer is being assigned which goes and gets the customer from the DB with the id of the ss_customer_id variable, and $cardID is being assigned to the API command to go get the customer and get the sources listed then echo will print the last4 of those sources, but for some reason it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
cardID = $customer->sources->data->last4;
```

Needs something looking more like:

```
cardID = $customer->sources->data[0]->card->last4;
```

Where:

- `data[0]` contains a reference to which of the `data` array items you want (you'll need to determine which one is the default payment method, and replace `0` with the id of it); and
- `card` needs to be inserted into your heirarchy

If you check the response object returned from creating the payment method, you will be able to see the hierarchy in the JSON response and go from there. It's also in the stripe event logs.

You can also get it from response objects from other calls. For example, from a payment intent:

```
payment_intent->charges->data[0]->payment_method_details->card->last4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix my issue, none of these answers helped I had to figure it out myself here is what I got.

```
require './stripe-php/init.php'; 
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("SK LIVE KEY");

$stripe = \Stripe\Customer::retrieveSource(
    $ss_customer_id,
    $ss_card_id,
    array()
);

$stripe2 = $stripe->toJSON();                                                
$JSON = $stripe2;

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($JSON, TRUE)),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                                                 
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
if(!is_array($val)) {                                            
  echo "<td>" .$key. "</td> <td>".$val ."</tr>";
 }
}
```

And this imports everything about the sources attached to the customer.

Which is exactly everything i needed,

It includes:
LAST4
EXPR month and year
Billing address
and more about the card.